# mySQL Are there advantages to using enum instead of two boolean fields?

Tags: mysql, enums, boolean, field

I'm building a table to log messages. I need to note when a message has been sent and if the message has been successfully delivered.

Are there advantages / disadvantages to using an `ENUM` type with values like `'ready', 'sent', 'delivered'` in an `ENUM` field over having two `boolean` fields like this:

```
| sent | delivered |
| true | false     |
```

Or is it purely a stylistic choice?

Comment: If you have two columns then it is possible to add a row with `{sent:false, delivered:true}` by mistake.

Comment: @SalmanA Care to put that as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the two set of values seem to depend on each other. 
For example a message cannot be `delivered` if it is not `sent`. 
Using multiple boolean fields makes it possible to store incorrect combination of values.

I would recommend that you use one field to store the status. That field could be an enum or an integer foreign key that joins to a status table ([discussed frequently](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20enum%20vs%20int%20performance)).

---

Having said that, using boolean fields is perfectly acceptable if fields are independent of each other.